# Wore ihram at Aysha masjid when travelling from madina

Tags: umrah, kaffarah

I travelled from madinah by the train to perform umrah. But I did not wear ihram in madinah. I went to the hotel in makkah, changed the clothes and went to masjid aysha to enter ihram. Is my umrah valid ? I have already left Saudi and got in to confusion. Do I have to slaughter a sheep now or can I fast instead? Please help me to clarify this doubt. May Allah bless you all.